# Java - order things in an arraylist according to an atribute

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Hi, i have an arraylist, lets call it "callcenterList" in that arraylist i will add objects of the "Call" class.

The "Call" objects have different atributes, some of them are "Status", "Month" and "Day" (Month and day when the call was received and the Status of it).

The status could be "Completed" or "Pending"

So a "Call" object would be like:

```
call1:
Atribute1 = whatever.
Atribute2 = whatever.
Month = 3
Day = 25
Status = Pending
```

So here is what im asked to do:

I need to show all the calls with status = Pending, and ordered by date.
How can i do this? If you need more info or more detailed please tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: Only storing the month and day of a `Call` (without the year) makes ordering by date ambiguous. Consider simply using one `Date` variable for this purpose.

Comment: Try out the `Comparator` interface. Make a new class that implements `Comparator<Call>`. Then write a method that compares your objects with the methods you like. Then call `Collections.sort(yourList, yourComparator);`

Comment: It looks like data from a database, if this is the case then it would be easiest and most performant to let the database do the job (pure sorting and filtering time) => SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using a `Comparator<Call>` class, one whose `compare(Call c1, Call c2)` method compares the attributes of interest of the two parameters and then returns 1, 0 or -1 depending on the results of the comparison. You can then use `Collections.sort(myList, myComparator)` to sort your collection based on the Comparator.

```
public class Call {
   private int value1;
   private int value2;
   public Call(int value1, int value2) {
      this.value1 = value1;
      this.value2 = value2;
   }
   public int getValue1() {
      return value1;
   }
   public void setValue1(int value1) {
      this.value1 = value1;
   }
   public int getValue2() {
      return value2;
   }
   public void setValue2(int value2) {
      this.value2 = value2;
   }
}
```

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Call> {

   @Override
   public int compare(Call c1, Call c2) {
      int firstCompare = Integer.compare(c1.getValue1(), c2.getValue1());
      if (firstCompare != 0) {
         return firstCompare;
      } else {
         return Integer.compare(c1.getValue2(), c2.getValue2());
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call sort(new CallComparator()) on the ArrayList, and pass a [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.htmlbQjVOJ3knAayzD1xd2TKIMhdZdQ)  to it. The list will then be sorted according to the orering that the comparator gives. If call #14 took place before call #7, then new CallComparator().compare(call14, call7) would return a value less than 0.

So, for the data you have given us, the comparator might be implemented as such:

```
public class CallComparator implements Comparator<Call> {
   @Override
   public int compare(Call c1, Call c2) {
        if (c1.getMonth() == c2.getMonth() 
             return c1.getDay() - c2.getDay();
        else 
             return c1.getMonth() - c2.getMonth();
        }
 }
```

This of course assumes you have getDay() and getMonth() methods in the Call class.

If you want to do this in reality, you probably want to save dates with the year as well. You could to that, and start the compare()-method body with checking the years. But that would be reinventing the wheel. The class Date has been around for a while in Java, but Java 8 introduced the really neat [time-package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), which is recommended to use instead. For your purposes, you could create a LocalDateTime object (or an Instant object, if you are operating across time zones) to hold the full date. You could then simply change the body of compare() to

```
return c1.getDate().compareTo(c2.getDate());
```

This would achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to filter your results as opposed to order them.  While you can accomplish this by first sorting it, then using an `Iterator` to remove the elements you don't care about, there's a lot more work involved in doing that as opposed to just filtering it.

**Note that if this is coming from the database, then filter it on the database side.** Depending on the volume of data, operations like this are more expensive to do in the backend than they are to do on the server.

Using [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), this is straightforward.

- Use a [`FluentIterable`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) to create an iterable which you can then chain operations to.
- Create a [`Predicate`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained#functions-and-predicates) upon which to only accept items that fit within the parameters you care about.
- Sort the resulted list in the order you want using a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  Keep in mind that this is different than a `Comparable`, where you mark a specific object as such; `Comparator` allows you to specify a new ordering that differs from the natural ordering at will.

Here's an example.  Assume that `Call` has methods `getStatus()` and `getDate()`, and that `getDate()` is `Comparable` (the `java.util.Date` class is).

```
List<Call> calls = ...
final List<Call> filteredCalls = FluentIterable.from(calls).filter(new Predicate<Call>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(final Call input) {
        return "pending".equals(input.getStatus());
    }
 }).toSortedList(new Comparator<Call>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Call firstCall, final Call secondCall) {
        return firstCall.getDate().compareTo(secondCall.getDate());
    }
 });
```

In Java 8, this expression becomes a lot more terse, and you don't require the use of a third party library.

```
final List<Call> filteredCalls = calls.stream()
                                .filter(c -> "pending".equals(c.getStatus()))
                                .sorted((left, right) -> left.getDate().compareTo(right.getDate()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```